# CloudFormation Multiline Substitution in YAML. Is it possible?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to do a multiline substitution in a CFT and it's just not happening. The error I am getting is

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: unsupported structure.`

Which is quite non-descript. I have the CFT plugin for intellij and it isn't giving me any syntax errors. Is such a thing supported? The problem line is at `Fn::Sub`

According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) it is.

Here is the sample I am working with. I have the whole CFT working with hardcoded values but I would like it working with imported values from the CFT that created the parts of the stack that I am trying to watch

code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: "Per ticket: CLOUD-1284"
Parameters:
  LogGroupName:
    Type: String
    Default: "ct/dev-logs"
    AllowedValues: ["ct/dev-logs","ct/prod-logs"]
    Description: Enter CloudWatch Logs log group name. Default is ct/dev-logs

  Email:
    Type: String
    Description: Email address to notify when an API activity has triggered an alarm
    Default: cloudops@
Resources:
  PolicyUpdates:
    Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
    Properties:
      FilterPattern:
        Fn::Sub:
        - >-
        { ($.eventSource = iam.amazonaws.com) &&
          (($.eventName = Update*) || ($.eventName = Attach*) || ($.eventName = Delete*) || ($.eventName = Detach*) ||($.eventName = Put*)) &&
          (($.requestParameters.roleName = ${Ec2Role}) || ($.requestParameters.roleName = ${RdsRole})) }
        - Ec2Role: !ImportValue infra-Ec2IamRole
        - RdsRole: !ImportValue infra-RdsIamRole

      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName
      MetricTransformations:
      - MetricValue: 1
        MetricNamespace: SpecialMetrics
        MetricName: PolicyUpdateMetrics

  PolicyUpdatesAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: " Policies have have been updated"
      AlarmActions:
      - Ref: AlarmNotificationTopic
      MetricName: PolicyUpdateMetrics
      Namespace: SpecialMetrics
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 10
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching

  S3BucketPolicyUpdates:
    Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
    Properties:
      FilterPattern: >-
        { ($.eventSource = s3.amazonaws.com) && (($.eventName = Put*) || ($.eventName = Delete*)) &&
        (($.requestParameters.bucketName = assets-us-east-1) || ($.requestParameters.bucketName = logs-us-east-1)) }
      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName
      MetricTransformations:
      - MetricValue: 1
        MetricNamespace: SpecialMetrics
        MetricName: S3BucketPolicyUpdateMetric

  S3BucketPolicyUpdatesAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: " S3 bucket security settings have been updated"
      AlarmActions:
      - Ref: AlarmNotificationTopic
      MetricName: S3BucketPolicyUpdateMetric
      Namespace: SpecialMetrics
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 10
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching

  AlarmNotificationTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      Subscription:
      - Endpoint: !Ref Email
        Protocol: email
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you just need to fix the syntax.

---

**The fix:**

Here's a simplified version of your code showing corrected syntax:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Test Stack
Resources:
  PolicyUpdates:
    Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
    Properties:
      FilterPattern:
        Fn::Sub:
        - >-
          { ($.eventSource = iam.amazonaws.com) &&
          (($.eventName = Update*) || ($.eventName = Attach*) || ($.eventName = Delete*) || ($.eventName = Detach*) ||($.eventName = Put*)) &&
          (($.requestParameters.roleName = ${Ec2Role}) || ($.requestParameters.roleName = ${RdsRole})) }
        - {Ec2Role: MyEc2Role, RdsRole: MyRdsRole}
      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroup
      MetricTransformations:
      - MetricValue: 1
        MetricNamespace: SpecialMetrics
        MetricName: PolicyUpdateMetrics

  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
```

On creating that stack the following Metric Filter is created:

```
▶ aws logs describe-metric-filters --query 'metricFilters[].filterPattern' 
[
    "{ ($.eventSource = iam.amazonaws.com) && (($.eventName = Update*) || ($.eventName = Attach*) || ($.eventName = Delete*) || ($.eventName = Detach*) ||($.eventName = Put*)) && (($.requestParameters.roleName = MyEc2Role) || ($.requestParameters.roleName = MyRdsRole)) }"
]
```

Thus, you would need to change your `Fn::Sub` to:

```
FilterPattern:
  Fn::Sub:
    - >-
      { ($.eventSource = iam.amazonaws.com) &&
        (($.eventName = Update*) || ($.eventName = Attach*) || ($.eventName = Delete*) || ($.eventName = Detach*) ||($.eventName = Put*)) &&
        (($.requestParameters.roleName = ${Ec2Role}) || ($.requestParameters.roleName = ${RdsRole})) }
    - {Ec2Role: !ImportValue infra-Ec2IamRole, RdsRole: !ImportValue infra-RdsIamRole}
```

---

**How to get better error messages:**

The first thing I did was run cloudformation validate-template:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cloudformation.yml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation:
  Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 23, column 45)
```

Since it's a YAML formatting issue, the [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) utility usually provides more information:

```
▶ yamllint cloudformation.yml 
cloudformation.yml
  23:45     error    syntax error: could not find expected ':'
```

Going into the vim editor and issuing a command:

```
:cal cursor(23,45)
```

Takes me to line 23, column 45 where I find the beginning of the string `${Ec2Role}`.

The first problem I see is that the indenting is wrong. That's actually the cause of that message.

By indenting lines 21-23 by 2 more spaces makes the template valid YAML. Then I got a more helpful response from cloudformation validate-template:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cloudformation.yml 

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation:
  Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected
  arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument
  to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string
```

At this point, it can be seen from the documentation that the call to `Fn::Sub` is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I literally ran that aws validate-template to get the error I got! Grrr! Ok, I am going to try your changes.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could be explained as I used your exact template to produce those errors. Different version of the CLI? I have:
`aws-cli/1.16.121 Python/2.7.15 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.12.111`.

Comment: `$ aws --version aws-cli/1.16.100 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.12.90` Has to be - no idea. Either way, you get a gold star 'cause it works!

Comment: Oh... I think I know what it is... [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1489#issuecomment-271766355)?